# ensemble learners, bagging and adaboosting

Tags: r, math, machine-learning, statistics, ensemble-learning

i have a implemented two ensemble techniques, i.e., `bagging` and `adaboosting` in r that should work with any learner.

my grid:

```
grids <- list(
              "knn" = expand.grid(k = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15))
             )
```

my variables:

```
n <- c(2, 4) 
boots <- createResample(trainData$BAD, times = 50, list = TRUE)
```

my bagging:

```
for(i in seq_along(grids)) { 

            method <- names(grids[i])

            for(j in 1:nrow(grids[[i]])) {
                grid <- data.frame(grids[[i]][j, ])
                colnames(grid) <- names(grids[[i]])

                # start bagging
                bagging <- foreach(k = 1:length(n)) %do% {

                    predictions <- foreach(m = 1:n[k], .combine = cbind) %do% {

                        tune <- train(BAD ~ ., data = trainData, method = method, trControl = ctrl, tuneGrid = grid, 
                                      metric = "ROC")

                        pred <- c(predict(tune, newdata = trainData, type = "prob")$BAD,
                                  predict(tune, newdata = testData, type = "prob")$BAD)
                    }
                    pred_means <- rowMeans(predictions) 
                }   
                resu_bag <- c(resu_bag, unlist(bagging))  
            }
        }
```

my adaboosting:

```
for(i in seq_along(grids)) { 
    method <- names(grids[i])

    for(j in 1:nrow(grids[[i]])) {
        grid <- data.frame(grids[[i]][j, ])
        colnames(grid) <- names(grids[[i]])

        # start boosting
        boosting <- foreach(k = 1:length(n)) %do% {

            predictions <- foreach(m = 1:n[k], .combine = cbind) %do% {
            train_boo <- trainData[boots[[m]], ]

            tune <- train(BAD ~ ., data = train_boo, method = method, trControl = ctrl, tuneGrid = grid, 
                          metric = "ROC")
            pred <- c(predict(tune, newdata = trainData, type = "prob")$BAD,
                      predict(tune, newdata = testData, type = "prob")$BAD)
          }
            pred_means <- rowMeans(predictions)
        }
        resu_boo <- c(resu_boo, unlist(boosting))  
    }
}
```

my questions:

1. could you please give an advice whether the implementation are correct?
2. the performance of the model is the same as of a single learner or even worse. why it happens? what do i do wrong?

thank you very much!

Comment: Machine learning issues could go to [datascience.stackexchange.com/](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more insight, here: Size of your data, number of variables, which are the metrics used to assess the performance of the models? How have you defined your parameters?

Comment: You could simplificate your exemple, using grids <- c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15) and adapting the situations where grids is used.

Comment: thank you for your answers!

1. i used three open credit scoring data sets (german credit data set, australian credit data set)

- please go here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+(German+Credit+Data)
- please go here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+(Australian+Credit+Approval)

2. To assess the performance I use AUC

I think the problem is in the variable "n" because I create to small bootstraps.